# Fileupload Not Working in php and not storing name in database

Tags: php, html, database

i am uploadig file to specific directory and saving name of the file in database.

My html code for form:

```
<form style='margin:15px;' method='post' action='commentheandler.php'>
    <textarea name='commentsub' rows='3' cols='90' required></textarea><br />
    <br/><input type='file' name='attachfile' /><br />";
    <br/><input type='hidden' name='cmember_id' value='" . $id . "'>
    <input type='hidden' name='tsreid' value='" . $id_t . "'>
    <input type='submit' name='comment' value='comment'>
</form>
```

commentheandler.php

```
<?php
    include "lib/db.php";
    if (isset($_POST['comment']))
    {
        $id_t = $_POST['tsreid'];
        $comment = $_POST['commentsub'];
        $created_id = $_POST['cmember_id'];

        $time = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");

        $target_dir = "logoimages/task/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["attachfile"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }

        $file = basename( $_FILES["attachfile"]["name"]); // used to store the filename in a variable

        ($file!=null)
        {   
           $insert=array("taskid"=>$id_t,"comment"=>$comment,"attachfile"=>$file,"createdby"=>$created_id,"created"=>$time,"isdelete"=>0);//storing the data in database
            $db->insert("taskcomment",$insert);
            $loc="location: taskhandler.php?id=" . $id_t . "";
            header($loc);
        }
        else {
            $insert=array("taskid"=>$id_t,"comment"=>$comment,"createdby"=>$created_id,"created"=>$time,"isdelete"=>0);

            $db->insert("taskcomment",$insert);
            $loc="location: taskhandler.php?id=" . $id_t . "";
            header($loc);
        }
    }
?>
```

This is not working i can't get any name in database.need suggestions. thanks in advance.

ohk i get it working by adding enctype="multipart/form-data" to form but any idea how can i limit file size also.?

Comment: first add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form tag`. Then check `print_r($_FILES)` to what you are getting during post.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp   try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form

Form should be,

```
 <form style='margin:15px;' method='post' action='commentheandler.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanx Buddy it worked.it just slipped through my mind. :)

Comment: "*Thanx Buddy it worked*", Hey @JigarSolanki : Please mark it as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find this answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

`enctype='multipart/form-data` is an encoding type that allows files to be sent through a POST. Quite simply, without this encoding the files cannot be sent through POST. If you want to allow a user to upload a file via a form, you must use this enctype. so please define enctype in your form tag like that

```
<form method='post' action='commentheandler.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: What is new in your answer Mukul, which Vinod Don't Have in his answer ?